# Windows server: canonical folder for simple executable?

Tags: windows

I’ve written a simple executable in Go that targets linux and windows. This is a server agent for a SaaS tool. I can see it being used in Task Manager actions and from powershell.

In my documentation i would like to suggest a canonical install folder. There is no installer, just a zip with a single exe.

I’m a Mac user. I would appreciate guidance on Windows best practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canonical program folders in Windows are `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`, and best practice would be to create an appropriate subfolder under one of those for your application.

Comment: Or use the system variables `%ProgramFiles%` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` and make your own folder there.

Comment: @bjoster That’s a good point, though technically speaking, those would be the environmental variables pointing at those canonical program folders.  I’m not sure what the implications of using the variable over the literal path would be, or if there’s any reason to use one over the other.